# Semantic versioning (semver) versus Maven convention versus artifact repository conventions - What versioning scheme to use?

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus, semantic-versioning, maven-publish

I am setting up a versioning scheme for a greenfield project and read a lot about [semver](https://semver.org/) and [the Maven convention](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN8855). I'm using the Nexus OSS repo manager (v3.13.0).

It's hard to settle on an authoritative scheme when in comes to versioning but I believe in the power of convention. While the semver document (link above) seems well written I notice clashes with how Maven seems to treat version numbers. The goal is to settle on a scheme that gives good ordering. Semver mentions that the pre-release label (the part that follows `Major.Minor.Patch-`) may have dot-separated segments, some of which **are numeric and are to be compared as such**, so one should not have zero padding such as `RC.09`. In practice, however, Maven (oracle link above, but is that authoritative?) treats everything after the first dash as one alphanumeric field, hence, one should use `RC09` and `RC10`.

***My question is, use zero-padding or not? I would love to adhere to `semver`, but I also need something that works.***

The added complexity is I'm not using Maven, but Gradle! But does that even matter? --> where is version ordering computed, in the build system or in the repo manager (Nexus in my case). See [what Nexus says on the topic](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html) - BUT, it references Maven, so I'm not sure if that applies to Gradle clients (or rather, to the [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plug-in). Then again, Gradle tries to mimic Maven when it comes to publishing standards. It's a mess!

Comment: First where do you see clashes between Maven and Semver? The linked oracle page is simply wrong for Maven 3+ (it was correct for Maven <=2).. Furthermore I recommend to read https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Version_Order_Specification furthermore I would simply suggest to things like `Major.Minor.Patch`and nothing more. It usually works for all cases. No RC etc. really makes sense from my point if view...The ordering of versions is needed if you like to find out the most recent one etc. and other situations. Maven also handles things like `1.34.678.12.3` against `1.34.677.12.3` correctly..?

Comment: Some more things: https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2017/02/04/apache-maven-how-version-comparison-works/

Comment: See https://versionmeta.org. Personally, I would use SemVer 2.0.0 or better (if ever they finally cut another version).  All the major packaging tools and product feeds have fairly decent support of SemVer and add support for specifying ranges in searches and dependency lists.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks vm. The links are helpful esp. this one - https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Version_Order_Specification. They made me understand that maven3 offers a more intuitive and flexible behaviour. For my case, after studying the link, this means concrtetely I can have versions like `1.2.3-someRandomQualifier-RC9`, with the `RC` and `9` being tokenized by the letter-digit transition and hence 9, 10, 11 etc. being numerical tokens with are compared naturally. There is no need to either explicitly separate (with dot or dash) nor to pad the `9` with a zero, to make it compare properly.

Comment: Correct. But the question is really if you need to use RC, someQualifier..I would suggest to think if you could handle things with simple three number version..

Comment: @khmarbaise I was envisioning a scheme that is fully automatic and flags a version as originating from any part of a Git tree. So I'd like to qualify the version with the branch name plus the index of the commit since branch diverged from master (normally I'd release from master where I use just major.minor.patch where patch is how many commits since major.minor got changed. But when I start having release branches I want those to have the major.minor.patch of the merge-base (fork point) plus branchName-#commit _on that branch_

Comment: @khmarbaisealso feel free to write an answer referring the links you mentioned. Meanwhile I found Nexus doc (https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465308-Can-I-delete-releases-from-Nexus-after-they-have-been-published-) that confirms the same scheme is used in the repo server - for example when ordering versions for retaining _newest N_. I'll add that to you answer.